# how can I label minor ticks in pgfplots without using "extra tick" option?

Tags: pgfplots

Is there any way to label minor ticks without using "extra tick" option? I would like to label the minor ticks very specifically like shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Yes, with `/pgfplots/log identify minor tick positions` as explained on p. 323 of the manual. If you wish to have a full-fledged answer, consider posting a full-fledged MWE. (I guess you'll get an answer anyway.)

Comment: Thanks  you. How can access to the manual?

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf